# Output exactly x number of characters to variable using read in Bash

Tags: string, bash, variables, character, echo

Does anyone know of an easier way to limit the output of an echo command to x number of characters within a bash script?

ie. Snippet:

```
echo "Enter string: "
read -N10 string
echo
```

To avoid exiting and continuing key press:

```
Enter string:
kkkkkkkkkk
$ kkkkkkkkkk
```

Basically, I want the output to cut off after 10 characters and the variable 'string' to hold those 10 characters so that I can use that string variable later on as opposed to the above scenario.

Any easier way to do this or something similar?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `echo "$string"`?

Comment: Well I need the output to be a certain number of characters ie.12 and to have that read into a variable

Comment: `echo "${string:0:$n}"` where `n` is the number of characters you want.

Comment: How would I implement that to the Enter string prompt? `echo "Enter string: "`

Comment: Or I should say once you entered a random string and then echoed out the set number of characters using the method you mentioned, how do you update the same string variable with the new character limit value?

Comment: Oh got it to work thank you @Barmar

Comment: FYI, you can specify the prompt as an option to `read`: `read -p "Enter string: " -r string`

Comment: Thank you @Barmar